# String manipulation in JS function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string say

```
((C1 AND C2) OR C3 AND C4)
```

now if input is '2' i am supposed to remove C2 and next operator which is OR, and rearrange the numbering... so output is

```
((C1 AND ) C2 AND C3).
```

**Test String input and output

```
----------STRING --------------------------- INPUT ---------------EXPECTED OUTPUT

1. (C1 AND C2 OR C3 AND C4)                <<3(Input)>>          (C1 AND C2 OR C3)

2.  C1 OR C2 AND (C3 OR C4) AND C5         <<2(Input)>>          C1 OR (C2 OR C3) AND C4
```

So i just need to delete the 'C' with the given input no and next operator if there is any , retain all brackets and re no the 'C' with ascending nos. this has to be done in a JS function

Comment: "this has to be done in a JS function" --- how much would you pay? It's not a red cross of programming.

Comment: Yea this one would take a while, you should have a shot at it first.

Comment: yeah m also tryin but lack of JS knowldege gettin me nowhere.. actually theres lot to be done... atleast dont vote down or comment with negativity if u cant help...

Comment: Okay, here's some guidance. Figure out how to split a string into two strings based on some delimiter. Or figure out how to replace characters in a string.

Comment: Pay particular attention to the 'methods' section: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Comment: @Garry DW and comments telling you to do some works first are actually encouraging what's in the FAQ so they are highly appropriate. SO is a place where you come if you are stuck when trying to solve a problem, it's not a crowd sourcing portal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the input remains consistent, then something along these lines would probably suit your needs. I know you said "retain all brackets" but that would make for an ugly output, so I opted for correcting the parentheses instead. You could easily take out that part.

```
function handleInput(str, input){
  var inArray = str.split(' ');
  inArray.forEach(function(v,i,a){
    if(v.indexOf("C"+input) > -1){
      if(v.indexOf('(') > -1 || v.indexOf(')') > -1)
        inArray = fixParen(inArray, input, v, i);
      else if(i+2 < a.length){
        inArray.splice(i,2);
        inArray = fixNumbers(inArray);
      }
      else
        inArray.splice(i-1,2);
      console.log(inArray.join(' '));
    }
  });
}
function fixParen(inArray, input, elem, index){
  var elemArray = elem.split('');
  var parenNumber = 0;
  if(elem.indexOf('(') > -1){
    elemArray.forEach(function(v){
      if(v == '('){
        parenNumber++;
      }
    });
    for (var i = index+2; parenNumber > 0; i+=2){
      var tempElem = inArray[i].split('');
      var n = tempElem.indexOf(')');
      if(n > -1){
        tempElem.splice(n,1);
        inArray[i] = tempElem.join('');
        parenNumber--;
      }
    }
    inArray.splice(index,2);
    return fixNumbers(inArray);
  }
  else{
    elemArray.forEach(function(v){
      if(v == ')'){
        parenNumber++;
      }
    });
    for (var i = index-2; parenNumber > 0; i-=2){
      var tempElem = inArray[i].split('');
      var n = tempElem.indexOf('(');
      if(n > -1){
        tempElem.splice(n,1);
        inArray[i] = tempElem.join('');
        parenNumber--;
      }
    }
    inArray.splice(index,2);
    return fixNumbers(inArray);
  }
}
function fixNumbers(inArray){
  var count = 1;
  inArray.forEach(function(v,i,a){
    if(v.indexOf('C') > -1){
      var tempElem = v.split('');
      var n = tempElem.indexOf('C');
      tempElem.forEach(function(val,ind,arr){
        if(parseInt(val,10))
          tempElem.splice(ind,1);
      });
      tempElem.splice(n+1,0,count);
      inArray[i] = tempElem.join('');
      count ++;
    }
  });
  return inArray;
}
```

This is actually a much simpler problem than it seems. First you should note that every important part of the string is evenly separated by a ' '. This lets us use `.split(' ')` to give us a nice array of all the useful parts. Next, the parentheses can only be on the `C` elements cutting down the amount of logic required. Then, every `(` has a corresponding `)` at some point allowing us to completely ignore testing the length of the string as we can assume that there is an element with the matching parentheses. Finally there are only two cases, it is the last `C` element so we remove the operator right before, or it is not the last and we remove the one after. Parentheses matching aside, the logic for this is pretty short.